# Xcode 3.2.2 refusing to open any project folders?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos, xcode3.2

I'm developing on a number of different machines and haven't used my laptop for a while. Today I tried to use for the first time after a couple of months only to find that Xcode steadfastedly refuses to open any .xcodeproj projects!?

I ended up uninstalling the older (I think it was 3.1) Xcode installation and re-installing the latest SDK from scratch, but I keep getting the same error even on newly created projects (e.g. New Project.. crash):

```
2/22/10 5:37:37 PM  Xcode[209]  [?T] File:  /SourceCache/DevToolsBase/DevToolsBase-1641/pbxcore/PBXProject.m
Line:   2630
Object: <PBXProject:0x2009c42a0>
Method: expandedValueForString:forConfigurationNamed:

Assertion failed: [NSThread isMainThread]
Backtrace:
  0  0x0000000100a3b6af -[PBXAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DevToolsInterface)
  1  0x00000001003110fa _XCAssertionFailureHandler (in DevToolsCore)
  2  0x000000010010be48 -[PBXProject expandedValueForString:forConfigurationNamed:] (in DevToolsCore)
  3  0x00000001001123df -[PBXProject intermediatesDirectoryForConfigurationNamed:] (in DevToolsCore)
  4  0x00000001001123a3 -[PBXProject intermediatesDirectory] (in DevToolsCore)
  5  0x00000001001122a5 -[PBXProject indexDirectory] (in DevToolsCore)
  6  0x0000000100112134 +[PBXProjectIndex indexArchivePathForProject:] (in DevToolsCore)
  7  0x000000010011202b -[PBXProjectIndex indexArchivePath] (in DevToolsCore)
  8  0x000000010024b18a __-[PBXProjectIndex initWithProject:]_block_invoke_ (in DevToolsCore)
  9  0x00007fff87164056 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_slow_invoke (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 10  0x00007fff87142943 _dispatch_queue_drain (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 11  0x00007fff871427a4 _dispatch_queue_invoke (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 12  0x00007fff8714234e _dispatch_worker_thread2 (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 13  0x00007fff87141c80 _pthread_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
 14  0x00007fff87141b1d start_wqthread (in libSystem.B.dylib)
```

Has anybody else come across this problem? Any caches beyond the ~/Library/Caches/xcodebuild to clean?

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Best regards,

Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I figured it out.. apparently there was something offending in the preferences file.

Deleting com.apple.Xcode.plist did the trick.

Comment: just re-notifying you about Abizern's comment